# Why my styled component not work with text-decoration?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to remove underline for my Link in react by using styled-components
if I use `style={{textDecoration: "none"}}` it will work but when I use `text-decoration: none;` in my styled components it won't work:
here is my js code:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "@reach/router";
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";

const StyleNavbarContainer = styled.nav`
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 100%;
  color: #d6d6d6;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
`;

const AppleLogo = styled.div`
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
`;

const StyleLinkList = styled.ul`
  display: inline-block;
`;

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  padding: 12px 10px;
  color: #d6d6d6;
  text-decoration: none;
`;

const Navbar = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <StyleNavbarContainer>
        <AppleLogo>
          <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
        </AppleLogo>
        <StyleLinkList>
          <StyledLink to="/">Mac</StyledLink>
        </StyleLinkList>
      </StyleNavbarContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

add my App.jsx file here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: I reproduced your problem on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-shape-v1ld5) and see no problem. Could you show the file you use the NavBar instead?

Comment: I just added my App.jsx file

Comment: Agh i fixed it. I need to remove the import bootstrap... weird

Answer (score 0):

Need to remove `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";` from App.jsx